# Indefinite integral 12

Tags: calculus

$$\int\frac{\tan{x}}{(x^2 +1)^2}dx$$
I tried the sub $$x=\tan{y}$$ to be
I=$$\int\frac{\tan({\tan{y})}}{\sec^2{y}}dy$$
But i could not go on any more ,does it has an anti-derivative or not ?

Comment: @amWhy Why did you delete your answer, and posted as a comment?

Comment: i think there is no solution in terms of the known elementary functions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner- How does one determine that?

Comment: You are correct, Ayush.  My bad!

Comment: @hussienmohamed The antiderivative cannot be written in terms of "standard" functions.

Comment: May you misprint and write "$\tan$" instead of "$\arctan$"?

Comment: @user355705 I did not misprint if it is arctan it would be obvious because the denominator would be the derivative of the numerator

Comment: It is not derivative of the numerator, but nevetheless the integaral could be then computed in terms of "elementary" functions.